# Accidentally removed execute permission from root directory.

Tags: permissions, chmod, root-filesystem

I accidentally did `chmod 770 /` which removed all access to the system. I booted to rescue mode, dropped to root shell and tried to `chmod 755 /`, but I get message `changing permissions of /: read-only file system` and nothing happens. How can I set root dir back to 755? Or am I completly locked out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make any changes to filesystem in recovery root shell , you have to remount the partition with read write permissions, `mount -o remount,rw /` . Then you can proceed with changing permissions of root directory

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, i was locked out and scared of losing everything but i somehow found the solution.
start the computer and go in advanced mode then choose recovery mode then a terminal like window will appear then navigate to the root directory and change the permissions back to 755.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP did, with the resulting error. Note Sergiy's answer that describes a solution -- and which was accepted by the OP.